# Is it possible to determine what language a .NET assembly was written in?

Tags: .net

Is there a method to determine the original language of a .NET assembly if the source code is not available?

Comment: Is this a one-time thing that you need to do or do you need an algorithm to that can determine the language for any given assembly?

Comment: @Igor-Zevaka: I was looking for something reproducible, perhaps via reflection, that I could use to generate metrics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to determine in which language a .NET Assembly was written ex post facto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579636/is-it-possible-to-determine-in-which-language-a-net-assembly-was-written-ex-pos)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really, but you can sometimes make a guess.

For example, if you have a VB.NET assembly containing anonymous types, the compiler-generated name in the assembly will look something like this:

```
VB$AnonymousType_T<T0, T1>
```

Anonymous types in a C# assembly look like this:

```
<>f__AnonymousType0<....>
```

Different compilers will implement these sorts of things slightly different. C++/CLI assemblies tend to have lots of types in the assembly with "funny" names (for things like functions that belong to the global scope and so on).

Visual Basic applications also reference the Microsoft.VisualBase assembly (though any .NET app can technically reference any assembly, so that's not a 100% indicator).

Comment: I should probably mention that the naming of anonymous types (and so on) is an implementation detail and likely subject to change in later versions of the compiler(s)...

Comment: It would appear you are the most correct. This related post includes additional heuristics, but you are fundamentally correct that it boils down to a 'guess'. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579636/is-it-possible-to-determine-in-which-language-a-net-assembly-was-written-ex-post

Answer (score 2):

You can guess by looking at what assemblies it references. If you see one of `Microsoft.CSharp` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, for example, that could give you a big hint.

Answer (score 1):

Not really since they're all roughly compiled to the same IL.