# how to check if assembly was written in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I want to check at runtime if an assembly was probably written in VB. It doesn't have to be a bullet-proof method. Maybe call `GetReferencedAssemblies()` and check for an assembly that all VB projects reference?

Comment: Similar question: [Is it possible to determine in which language a .NET Assembly was written ex post facto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579636/is-it-possible-to-determine-in-which-language-a-net-assembly-was-written-ex-post)

Comment: Why on Earth do you care what language was used? A major point of .NET is that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @John Saunders: To use it as a default preferred language when providing sample code to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a VB.NET Console application to my solution. It doesn't reference any assembly which is specific to VB.NET.

Comment: The assembly isn't listed in the GUI but the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly is referenced by default by a VB.NET console application.

Comment: As a VB developer I can confirm "Microsoft.VisualBasic" MUST be present in a VB compiled project. However I have in the past also added "Microsoft.VisualBasic" assembly reference to my rare C# projects for some ease of use functions. Though I'm sure anyone who would do this would be VB based developer anyways (just doesn't prove it is VB compiled project).

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question, since both are compiled down to MSIL and are supposed to be equal, You would have to look for implementation differences. There is very little information that I can find out there. But try looking at these two links.

1. http://www.devnewsgroups.net/dotnetframework/t22165-how-determine-code-vb-net.aspx
2. http://thedailyreviewer.com/dotnet/view/can-a-c-program-find-out-what-language-an-assembly-is-written-in-104571742